# How to properly pass information between subprocesses using pipes?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, pipe

I'm trying to get a simple nested pipe working via a Python script using subprocesses, but the output I'm getting is not making sense.

I've tried to redirect the output of `diff` to `grep` and from `grep` to `wc`, and then checking the output but without luck.

```py
import subprocess

diff = subprocess.Popen(("diff", "-y", "--suppress-common-lines", "file1.py", "file2.py"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
diff.wait()
grep = subprocess.Popen(("grep", "'^'"), stdin=diff.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
grep.wait()
output = subprocess.check_output(('wc', '-l'), stdin=grep.stdout)
print(output)
```

I would like this to result in the number of rows that differs between `file1.py`and `file2.py`, but instead I'm getting

```
b'       0\n'
```

From the command line, when I run `diff -y --suppress-common-lines file1.py file2.py | grep '^' | wc -l` it returns an integer.

Comment: Have you tried to read from the `grep.stdout` and `diff.stdout` streams to print their contents? It might tell you more about where this is failing. (It looks like the `wc -l` command is running correctly but receiving no content, hence the 0.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do in python subprocess call

```
("grep", "'^'")
```

In command line, you mean:

```
grep "'^'"
```

so the argument to `grep` is a 3-character string. If you do not mean that, simply do

```
("grep", "^")
```

Likely you will solve your problem.

PS: Similarly, do not expect any shell escape, variable substitution, etc. work in the argument to `subprocess.Popen()`. Those are shell functionalities, and the shell will massage them before passing on to the executable. So now you have to massage your own.

Comment: That would very likely cause it. It looks like wc -l is getting no content, so the grep probably just doesn't find anything.